# How do I show all files in a directory except those that have a certain extension AND display them in multiple columns?

Tags: grep, ls

Since I write in Python a lot it's kind of annoying to see .pyc files all the time and I would like to just hide them at this point. I tried the following, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to print in multiple columns.

```
ceasarbautista@hse140:~/Desktop/Statistics/statistics/probability$ ls
__init__.py     calculus.py     conditional.py      counting.pyc        distributions.pyc   event.pyc       objects.pyc
__init__.pyc        calculus.pyc        counting.py     distributions.py    event.py        objects.py      plots.py
ceasarbautista@hse140:~/Desktop/Statistics/statistics/probability$ ls | grep -v .pyc
__init__.py
calculus.py
conditional.py
counting.py
distributions.py
event.py
objects.py
plots.py
ceasarbautista@hse140:~/Desktop/Statistics/statistics/probability$ ls -C | grep -v .pyc
conditional.py      event.py
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
find . ! -name '*.pyc' -exec ls -dC {} +
```

Or with an advanced shell:

**`ksh`**: `ls -dC !(*.pyc)`

**`zsh`**: `setopt extendedglob` then `ls -dC ^*.pyc`

**`bash`**: `shopt -s extglob` then `ls -dC !(*.pyc)`

Answer (score 3):

Filter through `column`.

```
ls | grep -v '\.pyc$' | column
```

Comment: So this works pretty well except that sometimes I get something like this: https://gist.github.com/1308159