# ls command - define number of columns

Tags: command-line, ls, coreutils

Is there a way to define the number of columns in `ls` output?

I got this far: `ls -C` sorts in columns and `ls -1` produces one column. `--tabsize =` option to produce two columns resulted in what looks like [this image here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2008-05/pngJwolqzthdq.png) [which originates [in this post](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2008-05/msg00150.html)].

Learning that the the [command assumes that a column is eight characters wide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23171/why-does-the-column-command-not-align-columns-properly) I tried `width=` and but didn't get far.

**Question**: How to define the number of rows with `ls` 'on-board tools' → without another command, like `column`?

Comment: `ls -c` sorts by ctime.

Comment: @HaukeLaging edited the question; thanks for the hint!

Comment: You can also just write your own script, I did so some years ago and use it all the time: http://synodins.com/scripts/ls_crystal/. By either writing your own or using mine you have complete control over how the script operates.

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson My main concern is to stick as close to the Unix Philosophy as close as possible; thus I try to crank out the most of each command via it's options. But nevertheless thanks for the link. I'm watching and learning.

Comment: `ls -w60` puts the files in three columns for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to pipe `|` your `ls` output. Programs like `sed` or `cut` can sort out data as long as you know what your delimiter is. Most often in column spacing your delimiter is a tab.

However I don't know of many ways or reasons that you would want to split your `ls` output into columns. You can always pipe your output to `more` and it will make your data easier to read.

Comment: `ls -l | cut -d " " -f n` where n is the column

Answer (score 7):

No. `ls` does not have this capability [(and few would want it to)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy).

Comment: I highly value and appreciate the Unix philosophy, but I also wondered of how far the options would get me.

Comment: I understand. The parens were more of a side note than a directive.

Comment: Good answer since it clearly answered the question but I'm not sure "few would want it to" is on the mark. It looks like there's lots of folks who want the option on occasion. Based on the citation, shouldn't `ls` drop support for `ls -1`, too?

Comment: @jww: All `-1` does is force `ls` to use the same format that it would if you were piping its output to another program.

Answer (score 4):

Just override the width parameter with 1:

```
ls -w 1
```

Works great for me!

Comment: This worked well for me!  However you should know that is is about number of CHARACTERS, not columns.  Despite this it can basically do the job. `ls -w1` means that after the dir is printed if the column position is greater than 1 it will newline, i.e. always.  `ls -90` on the other hand means let the line width be up to 90 which effectively means two columns.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `ls` doesn't support this. You'd have to do something like `ls -1 | xargs -n 2` (or just `ls | xargs -n 2` should also work).

Answer (score 2):

I tested these command on Linux Debian in the terminal.  If your terminal is wide enough, just stating "ls" will give columns but it won't use all the space (width) of the terminal.  I made the terminal as wide as the screen and "ls" just produced 4 columns.  Problem is if you pipe this into "more" you loose the columns.

Next I used "ls -w200" in the terminal as wide as the screen (200 is the 'assumed screen width').  I got 5 columns (instead of 4 previously with just "ls") now and that takes up the full width of my screen -- everyone knows that this will be affected by the length of your file names.  Now it is one more column then "ls" by itself and the full screen width is used.  Again, like "ls", if I pipe the command into "more" ("ls -w200 | more") you loose the columns (i.e. just have one column).

So this is as close as you can get to multiple columns.

Note: I tried the command "ls -w2000" with terminal width maximized. The output was one line with a "wrap around" with 2 spaces between directory entries.  It looks messy but displays all entries in the directory in the shortest way.

Answer (score 1):

This is less about the number of columns and more about what shall be output. You cannot configure all the fields but you can hide owner and group by `-g` and `-G` and configure the time by `--time-style=`.

Comment: My bad - I used the lower case option where the upper case should be, as you pointed out correctly. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 1):

If using the `zsh` shell, you can always use its `print` builtin which supports printing in columns and globbing:

```
$ touch {1..20}; mkdir d{1..5}
$ print  -rC4 - *
1   16  4   d2
10  17  5   d3
11  18  6   d4
12  19  7   d5
13  2   8
14  20  9
15  3   d1
$ print  -arC4 - *
1   10  11  12
13  14  15  16
17  18  19  2
20  3   4   5
6   7   8   9
d1  d2  d3  d4
d5
$ print  -rC4 - *(n)
1   8   15  d2
2   9   16  d3
3   10  17  d4
4   11  18  d5
5   12  19
6   13  20
7   14  d1
$ print  -rC4 - *(M)
1    16   4    d2/
10   17   5    d3/
11   18   6    d4/
12   19   7    d5/
13   2    8
14   20   9
15   3    d1/
$ touch $'a\nb'
$ print  -rC4 - *(:q)
1        16       4        d1
10       17       5        d2
11       18       6        d3
12       19       7        d4
13       2        8        d5
14       20       9
15       3        a$'\n'b
```

`-a`  for *across*, `M` for `M`ark (like `ls -p`), `n` for numerical order (similar to GNU `ls -v`), `:q` to quote (akin to GNU `ls -Q`). See also the `D` qualifier to include hidden files (like `ls -A`).

Of course, you can combine all and more:

```
$ print  -arC4 - *(nDM:q)
1        2        3        4
5        6        7        8
9        10       11       12
13       14       15       16
17       18       19       20
a$'\n'b  d1/      d2/      d3/
d4/      d5/      .hidden
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your file in a text directory, slice and reformat it accordingly with alt tabs and afterwards give it a more options as a pipe alias.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).